# How does Python implement str[::-1]?

Tags: python, slice, reverse

Consider a python line:

```
str[::-1]
```

I see it's very fast, and way more faster than some **O(n)** solution and also memory saving. What algorithm does Python use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, have you tried any quick-and-dirty tests? Here is a first-pass:

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: def reverse_list_time(my_list):
   ...:     start  = time.time()
   ...:     reversed = my_list[::-1]
   ...:     stop = time.time()
   ...:     return stop - start
   ...: 

In [3]: reverse_list_time(list(range(1000)))
Out[3]: 1.33514404296875e-05

In [4]: testing_lists = (list(range(n)) for n in range(1000,100000,500))

In [5]: testing_lists
Out[5]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f7786bd97d8>

In [6]: results = list(map(reverse_list_time,testing_lists))
```

And here are my results

[image]

That looks roughly O(n) to me.

If that doesn't convince you, here is [the implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2544). It looks like a pretty straight forward O(n) solution to me. This is the meat of it:

```
    else {
        result = PyList_New(slicelength);
        if (!result) return NULL;

        src = self->ob_item;
        dest = ((PyListObject *)result)->ob_item;
        for (cur = start, i = 0; i < slicelength;
             cur += step, i++) {
            it = src[cur];
            Py_INCREF(it);
            dest[i] = it;
        }

        return result;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python's [`dis.dis`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#dis.dis) module to disassemble `str[::-1]`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def reverse_(str_):
...     return str_[::-1]
...
>>> dis.dis(reverse_)
  6           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (str_)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (-1)
             12 BUILD_SLICE              3
             15 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

You can see what each instruction means in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions).  For [`LOAD_FAST`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l1111) the docs say:

> Pushes a reference to the local `co_varnames[var_num]` onto the stack.

`co_varnames` is a structure that is always present with a code object.  In this case, it is `str_`:

```
>>> reverse_.__code__.co_varnames
('str_',)
```

The next instruction, [`LOAD_CONST`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l1123), is described like this:

> Pushes `co_consts[consti]` onto the stack.

The value that was pushed onto the stack is `None` (`dis` is helpful and looked it up for you).  The next two instructions are `LOAD_CONST` instructions that push the values `None` and `-1` onto the stack.

The next instruction, [`BUILD_SLICE`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l2777), is described as:

> Pushes a slice object on the stack. argc must be 2 or 3. If it is 2, `slice(TOS1, TOS)` is pushed; if it is 3, `slice(TOS2, TOS1, TOS)` is pushed. See the [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#slice) built-in function for more information.

`TOS2, TOS1, TOS` represent the values on the stack `None, None, -1`, which are pushed to the `slice()` object from the stack (the object becomes `slice(None, None, -1)`).

[`BINARY_SUBSCR`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l1374) is described as:

> Implements `TOS = TOS1[TOS]`.

This means that Python computes `str_[sli]` where `sli` is the `slice()` object pushed to the stack in the previous instruction.  It's the equivalent of

```
>>> str_[slice(None, None, -1)]
```

Finally, [`RETURN_VALUE`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/45b1ae1ef318/Python/ceval.c#l1863):

> Returns with TOS to the caller of the function.

The last instruction returns the result of the previous step, which is the reversed `str_`.

## Summary

> I see it's very fast, and way more faster than some O(n) solution and also memory saving.

In fact, reversing a list by slicing involves more memory overhead than some other reversal methods in Python.  Long story short (and without going down a long rabbit hole), the greater memory overhead occurs because the slicing operation returns a whole list.

One alternative method might be: generating an iterator using [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed), which is usually more performant for memory and time (although, generating a list from this iterator is time-consuming).

> What algorithm does Python use in this case?

To make a long story short: Python loads the variable `str`, builds a `slice(None, None, -1)` object, implements `str[slice(None, None, -1)]` ([source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/listobject.c#l2408)), and returns the reversed `str`.